# loading resources in non root urls laravel 5.1

Tags: php, web, laravel-5.1

I have a problem in loading css and javascript files in head and footer in laravel 5.1
If my route is very long like this

```
www.ex.com/a/b/c
```

It gives me

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

But if my route is short, this message doesn't appear the console.

Comment: Can you show how you attempt to load these resources?

Comment: i am using href={{asset('css/t.css')}} for example i am head  part and footer to call resources

Comment: If you want to load an asset from multiple folders you have to specify the full path, like: **asset('a/b/c/css/t.css')**.

Comment: ok thanks , it's working now

Comment: I'll put this as an answer so the question can be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load an asset from multiple folders you have to specify the full path, like: **asset('a/b/c/css/t.css')**.